# regex php find match between 2 strings including wildcard

Tags: php, regex

I want to find all result that have  $string_before [ MATCH ] anytext $string_after

PHP CODE :

```
$page = "anything/pages/Reading/120002/anything><div class='test'>";

$string_before = '/pages/Reading/';
$string_after = '/(.*?)><div class';
$regex= "'/".$string_before."([^#]+)".$string_after."'/";

preg_match_all($regex, $page, $matches); 
var_dump($matches);

// I should be getting "120002"  in the example above
```

The code above doesn't work... the output is  NULL
any ideas...
Thanks

### MODIFICATIONS

I now tried this:

```
$page = "anything/pages/Reading/120002/anything><div class='test'>";

$delimiter = "#";
$string_before = '/pages/Reading/';
$string_after = '/(.*?)><div class=';
$regex = $delimiter.$string_before."([^#]+)".$string_after.$delimiter;

echo $regex.'<br>';

preg_match_all($pattern, $page, $matches); 
var_dump($matches);
```

my regex is:

```
#/pages/Reading/([^#]+)/(.*?)>
```

So there's a problem with the $string_after not outputting properly...

and I get the following 2 errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: pattern on line 66 (that's the preg_match_all)

Warning: preg_match_all(): Empty regular expression  on line 66
NULL
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It doesn't work... how can I get the result    120002

Comment: What "does not work" mean? Does it output exactly "I DO NOT WORK" to the screen as a result?

Comment: Not only `NULL` actually, but a warning additionally.

Comment: I don't have any warning.. the page just shows NULL

Comment: That's because you don't check your error log and don't have `display_errors` set. Check here http://ideone.com/2ISddw to see the real output

Comment: You have too many delimiters.  the resulting expression will be: //pages/Reading/([^#]+)/(.*?)><div class/ and you either  need to escape the slashes in the path \/pages\/Reading\/ or easier change the delimiter. #/pages/Reading/([^#]+)/(.*?)><div class#

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '/' in line 63  (that's the preg_match_all  line)

Comment: Please, can you provide the regex after it has been put together by php.

Comment: @Misunderstood: `.+` cannot be "less" greedy than `.*`. The quantifier is either greedy, or not. It's boolean. So they are both greedy. So the `?` quantifier is necessary there.

Comment: @Andie2302 I've updated the question with the modification and my regex as result.. but it's still not working

Comment: The plus in this expression should be removed "([^#]+)" to "([^#])" unless you are looking for more than one octothorpe (#).  the plus means one or more of the preceding character. If you were looking for one # or two ## then you'd use "([^#]?)".  Just realized you cannot use # as a delimiter because it is used in the expression.

Comment: @Misunderstood I changed my delimiter to @ and took out the + sign, but I get the same result.....heres my code: $delimiter = "@";
$string_before = '/pages/Reading/';
$string_after = '/(.*?)><div class=';
$regex = $delimiter.$string_before."([^#])".$string_after.$delimiter;

Comment: Change the # in  "$delimiter = "#"; " to any character not used in the expression.

Comment: It would have worked either way with the escape slashes or changing the delimiters. You changed $regex to $pattern as I posted the comment.  I think the change of delimiter is better, less confusing and less characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to escape your pattern (ie. replace all / with \/)

```
$page = "anything/pages/Reading/120002/anything><div class='test'>";

$string_before = '\/pages\/Reading\/';
$string_after = '\/(.*?)><div class';
$regex= "/".$string_before."([^#]+)".$string_after."/";

preg_match_all($regex, $page, $matches); 
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: It's not working.. my $regex = '/\/pages\/Reading\/([^#]+)\/(.*?)>

Notice: Undefined variable: pattern on line 65

Warning: preg_match_all(): Empty regular expression on line 65
NULL

Comment: Your regex should be this: /\/pages\/Reading\/([^#]+)\/(.*?)><div class/

Comment: I see what the problem was. Fixed my answer. You don't need the extra single quotes where you were adding the delimiter to the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

PHP regular expressions take delimiters before and after. You've set your delimiters to `'/`, which won't work because 1) it's two characters, and 2) you use several slashes in the `$string_before` and `$string_after` variables.

If you change it to something else, like this, it'll work and you'll get your results in `$matches[1]`:

```
$regex= "@".$string_before."([^#]+)".$string_after."@";
```

Comment: It's not working.. my $regex = @\/pages\/Reading\/([^#]+)\/(.*?)> Notice: Undefined variable: pattern on line 65 Warning: preg_match_all(): Empty regular expression on line 65 NULL

Comment: 1) You are escaping your slashes even though you don't have to because we changed delimiters. 2) Your expression is called $regex, not $pattern. Change your preg_match_all() call accordingly.